# DataSet XML export is empty

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I've got in-memory dataset with couple of tables that is populated in code. Data-bound grids on the gui show table contents without a problem.

Then I try to export the dataset into XML:

```
ds.WriteXml(fdSave.FileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

and get empty XML (with couple of lines regarding dataset names but without any tables)

If I export table directly I've got all the data but dataset name is obviously wrong:

```
ds.Fields.WriteXml(fdSave.FileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

What am I missing? Is there any reasonable way to write the whole dataset into file?

Answer (score 1):

ok, silly me. was clearing dataset tables collection before populating it...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation on DataSet.WriteXml:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135425.aspx

and on XmlWriteMode:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlwritemode.aspx

Try using XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema.  The docs say for XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema "If the DataSet does not have a current schema, nothing is written."

Comment: nope, IgnoreShema doesn't help

why wouldn't be any schema there if tables are defined in the dataset and can be saved by themselves?

Comment: Have you tried WriteXml without the XmlWriteMode option, and just the filestream or filename?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb27k0tf(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you must add the data tables to your dataset like,
*ds.Tables.Add(datatable1);*

then write export it into the schema